# Async request module in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am creating a project using Node.js. I want to call my requests in parallel. For achieving this, I have installed the async module. Here is my code:

```
var requests = [{
    url:url,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + req.cookies.apitoken
    },
    json: finalArr,
}];

async.map(requests, function(obj, callback) {

    // Iterator function
    request(obj, function(error, response, body) {

        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

            // Transform data here or pass it on
            var body = JSON.parse(body);
            callback(null, body);
        }
        else {
            var body = JSON.stringify(body);
            console.log(body)
            callback(error || response.statusCode);
        }
    });
})
```

I got `undefined` every time in `console.log(body)`. When I am using [GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) requests using this module for other requests then everything works fine.

Comment: What if you use something like Fiddler or Postman to make the API call. What response to you get back from your POST and how does it differ from the GET?

Comment: A GET request should have an empty body... you're saying req.body is populated on GET but not on POST?

Comment: I mean async module works with get request,but for post request i got undefined .But actually this api give me result when is checked the postman

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the `request` module, but didn't tag it as such.

If I'm right, then your options object is incorrect, from [the documentation](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback) there's not a `data` key that's respected.  Instead, you should use `body` or `formData` or `json` depending on what kind of data you're pushing up.  From your headers, I'd go with `json`.

```
var requests = [{
    url:url,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { // Content-Type header automatically set if json is true
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + req.cookies.apitoken
    },
    json: finalArr,
}];
```

Comment: Then you're missing something that the API you're hitting expects, and so it's not sending a body back.